# Impossible User Registration

Tags: wp-admin, login, user-registration

I do have a client wordpress site in which I am the only one who have the Administrator login account. The client website doesn't have any registration form or any widget that allows any user to register. I even disabled the "Anyone can register" on the General Settings. But how come someone still manage to register an Admin account and eventually deleted and remove my Admin login credentials at the end.

Could anyone help me explain how did that happened? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you disable registration, if the server has WP-CLI installed and if someone has ssh access then an admin user can easily be created using following command:

`wp user create bob bob@example.com --role=administrator`

Thus, that admin user can login and remove other user account easily.

[image: Creating Admin User with WP-CLI]

[Check this](https://wp-cli.org/commands/) to know about all the possibilities through WP-CLI commands.